# Dynamic nested dictionary using Python

Tags: python, dictionary, dynamic, nested

I have a dataframe like this:

```
from    to
B       C
A       B
D       E
D       F
B       D
```

I want to create a nested dictionary than contains `from` and `to` values. The final output will look like this:

```
{ "A": {
          "B": {
                   "C":
                   "D": {
                           "E": {},
                           "F": {},
                        }
               }
         }
}
```

My code is:

```
d = dict()
curr = d
for p, c in [("B", "C"), ("A", "B"), ("D", "E"), ("D", "F"), ("B", "D")]:
    
    # First time
    if not d:
        d.setdefault(p, {}).setdefault(c, {})
    
    # Check if p is a parent
    if p in d:
        curr = curr.setdefault(p, {}).setdefault(c, {})
        
    else:
        if c in d:
            curr = d
            curr.setdefault(p, {}).setdefault(c, d.get(c))
            del d[c]
        else:
            curr = d
            for k, v in curr.items():
                if p in v:
                    curr = v
                    curr.setdefault(p, {}).setdefault(c, {})
            else:
                curr.setdefault(p, {}).setdefault(c, {})
```

The result is:

```
{'A': {'B': {'C': {}}},
 'B': {'D': {'E': {},
             'F': {}}}}
```

I don't know how to check whether one key is already a parent or a child and substitute if it's already a child/parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
pairs = [("B", "C"), ("A", "B"), ("D", "E"), ("D", "F"), ("B", "D")]

d = {}
for a, b in pairs:
    d.setdefault(a, {})[b] = d.setdefault(b, {})

ok = {'A': d['A']}
print(ok)
```

prints

```
{'A': {'B': {'C': {}, 'D': {'E': {}, 'F': {}}}}}
```

Here is version that is a bit more dynamic and supports multiple top level keys.

```py
import json

pairs = [
    ("B", "C"),
    ("A", "B"),
    ("D", "E"),
    ("D", "F"),
    ("B", "D"),
    ("z", "x")
]

d = {}
something_points_to = set()
for a, b in pairs:
    something_points_to.add(b)
    d.setdefault(a, {})[b] = d.setdefault(b, {})

root_keys = [key for key in d if key not in something_points_to]
final_result = {key: d[key] for key in root_keys}


print(json.dumps(final_result, indent=4))
```

That should give you:

```
{
    "A": {
        "B": {
            "C": {},
            "D": {
                "E": {},
                "F": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "z": {
        "x": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very cleaver but as an answer it really needs to be explained. I do like how `d` is constructed and leveraged though. Is there an easy way to get `A` so that you don't need to know it to generate `ok` without say calculating depth?

Comment: What is the general idea of this solution? Could you please explain it more details? Thanks

Comment: A dictionary of from and two is built up over time but these items are references so as we go pair by pair, ultimately the tree (and all sub-trees) are constructed. Again though these are references so not a memory hog.  In the end, the root "A" is used to print the final sub-tree.  To see it in action, `print(d)` at every iteration of the loop

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to understand the algorithm under the hood of those given solutions. For now, the solution is working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use recursive to create nested dictionary starting from top-level
(Assuming the dataframe is similar)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "from": ["B", "A", "D", "D", "B"],
    "to": ["C", "B", "E", "F", "D"]
})
```

Find the root

```
roots = set(df["from"].values) - set(df["to"].values)
```

Use the roots node and dataframe with recursion to generate the nested dictionary (desired output):

```
tree = {}

def build_tree(df, node):
    if node not in df["from"].values:
        return {}
    else:
        children = df.loc[df["from"] == node, "to"].values
        subtree = {}
        for child in children:
            subtree[child] = build_tree(df, child)
        return subtree

for root in roots:
    tree[root] = build_tree(df, root)

print(tree)
```

Ouptut:

[image]